# Print row and column labels for strings grid in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-3.7, nested-lists

My apologies if a similar question has been asked in the passed. But based on what I have seen so far, none of them have been much of a help. I am a python noob and my task is to present a gameboard of ascii sysmbols read from a txt file into a grid of strings with rows and columns labelled.

I first read my txt file to a 2D list using a separate function:

```
def readLevel(n):
    '''takes an integer as argument representing the level number
    and reads the appropriate game board file. Returns it as a 
    2D list of strings.'''

try:
    file = open(f'./levels/ascii_level{n}.txt','r')
    game_board = []

    for line in file:
        ascii_string = list(line.rstrip())
        game_board.append(ascii_string)

    file.close()

    return game_board

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Failed to read level {n}. Game ending.")
```

The above code will read the text file as:

```
[['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'], ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'], ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'], ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'], ['#', '@', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]
```

I then created a function that takes this 2D list and displays it as a grid of strings. Here is my code

```
def displayBoard(gameBoard):
'''takes a gameboard 2D list as argument and displays it to the 
console with row and column labels included'''


    for row in gameBoard:
        board_grid = ''
        for ele in row:
            board_grid += str(ele)
        print(board_grid)
```

When I ran this function as displayBoard(readLevel(1)), I get my expected output:

```
###@@###%
##@@&&&#%
@#####&#%
@@@@###%%
#@%%%%%%%
```

But, I need to get my grid to look like this.

[image: I am having difficulty in adding the row and column labels to this grid in the form:]

I know that the column corresponds to the elements of the sublists in my gameboard 2D list and rows correspond to the number of sublists.

So I tried manipulating my code but have not had any success:

```
def displayBoard(gameBoard):
'''takes a gameboard 2D list as argument and displays it to the 
console with row and column labels included'''
    r = 0
    n = 0
    for i in range(0,len(gameBoard)):
       r += 1
       for j in range(0,len(gameBoard[i])):
          n += 1
       print(r)
       print(n)
       for row in gameBoard:
          board_grid = ''
          for ele in row:
             board_grid += str(ele)
          print(board_grid)
```

Again, given my beginner level, I am not familiar with any of the fancy python modules to get the desired result. Just the basic knowledge of nested list manipulation is required to get this right.

I appreciate your help

Comment: The `012345678` should be printed _in one line_, before anything else is printed. Row indices, on the other hand, can be printed sequentially, before each row is printed

Comment: Could you please show by editing my code above? I tried to follow up what you said but have not got it. The 012345678 is dependent on the elements of my sublist so I tried to do it within a for loop. I am doing this because I have 5 different txt files, each generating different sized  sublists in my 2D list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g = [['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'],
    ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'],
    ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'],
    ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'],
    ['#', '@', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]


def displayBoard(gameBoard, col_digits=2):
    n_rows = len(gameBoard)
    n_cols = len(gameBoard[0])
    result = (
        ' ' * (col_digits + 1) + ''.join(str(i) for i in range(n_cols)) + '\n'
        + ' ' * (col_digits + 1) + ''.join('-' for i in range(n_cols)) + '\n')
    for i, row in enumerate(gameBoard):
        result += (
            str(i).zfill(col_digits) + '|'
            + ''.join(str(elem) for elem in row) + '\n')
    return result


print(displayBoard(g))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   012345678
   ---------
00|###@@###%
01|##@@&&&#%
02|@#####&#%
03|@@@@###%%
04|#@%%%%%%%
```

---

The key differences / missing elements are:

- construct the output `str` rather than printing it on the spot. This is mostly irrelevant at this stage, but arguably a better design. To print everything on the spot, just replace `result +=` with `print` (eventually with `end=''` if the string does not end with a `\n`).
- extensively use `''.join(items)` to construct a string from a loop. This is mostly equivalent to `result = ''; for item in items: result += item`
- use `str.zfill()` to add zeros up to a certain string length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def displayBoard(gameBoard):
    '''takes a gameboard 2D list as argument and displays it to the 
    console with row and column labels included'''


    # Pad board by three spaces
    lpad = ' ' * 3

    # Column length
    col_len = len(output[0])

    # List of numbers from 0 through col_len - 1
    num_list = ''.join([str(i) for i in range(col_len)])

    # Ddivider
    divider = '-' * col_len

    # First part of stirng output
    msg = f'{lpad}{num_list}\n{lpad}{divider}'

    # Iterate rows
    for i in range(len(output)):
        # Join elements of row with no space in between
        values = ''.join([i for i in output[i]])
        # Append values to mesage with a 0, row number, and vertical line
        msg += f'\n0{i}|{values}'

    # Print results
    print(msg)
```

Output:

```
   012345678
   ---------
00|###@@###%
01|##@@&&&#%
02|@#####&#%
03|@@@@###%%
04|#@%%%%%%%
```